# Please help understand the use case of unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have 2 scripts.

1. It runs a load test using locust, collects the output in dict format, then pass it to the 2nd script.
2. 2nd script will accept a dict as input from script-1, parses it, creates a json payload and sends the data to an api endpoint where it stores in some db.

The application starts running from the 1st script and all the functionalities are working well. I have never worked on a unit testing. My question here is:
What can be tested here using unit testing in order to keep proper standard of building an application.

script-1. (suppose locust is running in already)

```
def on_slave_report(data):
    send_to_db(data)

events.slave_report += on_slave_report
```

script-2.

```
def send_to_db(data):
     send_it(take_only_needed(data))

def take_only_needed(data):
     needed=data[stats]
     payload = json.dumps({'stats' : needed, 'bla': bla})
     return payload

def send_it(payload):
     requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: What are you about to test?  The scripts you have shown, or the application you mention?

Comment: not the application, just script-2.

Answer (score 0):

For the two functions `send_to_db` and `send_it`, unit-testing does not make much sense: Both functions consist only of interactions with other components/functions.  Since unit-testing aims at finding those bugs which can be found in the isolated units, there are no bugs which unit-testing could find.  Bugs in such interaction dominated code lie more in the following area: Are you calling the right functions in the right order with the right values for the parameters, are the parameters in the right order, are the results/return values delivered in the expected way and format?  And, answers for all these questions can not be found in the isolated code, but only in code where the respective components truly interact - and this is integration-testing rather than unit-testing.

The only function in your script-2 that makes sense to unit-test is `take_only_needed`: This function performs actual computations.  It also has the nice property that it only has dependencies which (probably) do not cause testing problems and thus probably don't need mocking.

Conclusion: Perform unit-testing for `take_only_needed`, for the others skip unit-testing and test them during interaction testing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you think I can mock requests.POST() method here?. I am catching return codes 200/400 to understand success/invalid payload, and reporting rest of the codes as error.